# Inserting an array in MongoDb

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have an array in php and I want to insert it in MongoDb.

Suppose:

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
```

and I want to create a document as

```
{
     {
         "user":user1,
          cars":["volvo","BMW","Toyota"]
     }
}
```

How do  I achieve this?

Comment: Do do that you  write a query

Comment: The array is being received from a different page and i need to insert it into the mongodb collection. So all I have is an array variable that corresponds to car in this question and need to insert it in mongodb in given format.

Comment: How have you tried to insert this data into MongoDB? Could you show us your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial might help you out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_php.htm

Specifically down around this section.

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();
   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->mycol;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";
   $document = array( 
      "title" => "MongoDB", 
      "description" => "database", 
      "likes" => 100,
      "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
      "by", "tutorials point"
   );
   $collection->insert($document);
   echo "Document inserted successfully";
?>
```

So in your case you'd want something like

```
$document = array(
  'user' => 'user1',
  'cars' => array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"),
);
```

Comment: what i meant was, do i need to iterate over the array and update collection with each of the value of array or can i do something as  array('user'=> 'user1' , 'cars'=> array($cars))

Comment: @ShubhamSharma no you don't have to iterate over the array and update each value. Looking at http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.updates.php as well as the link I mentioned earlier, you should be able to do `$collection->update(array('user' => 'user1'), array('$set' => array("cars" => $cars)));` where $cars is your array of cars.